# How to make API call in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I make API call in react like below.
First, there is an API address in html script.

```
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=s=services"
></script>
```

Second, get some result using method.

```
getCoor = () => {
    console.log(this.addressState.departure.road);


const geocoder = new window.daum.maps.services.Geocoder();

geocoder.addressSearch(this.addressState.departure.road, (result, status) => {
      if (status === window.daum.maps.services.Status.OK) {
        console.log(result[0].x, result[0].y);
      }
    });
  };
```

And, now I wanna make this in Nodejs.
But I don't know where I should put the method function in the POST request.
Could you recommend some solution?

```
 rp({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: `https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=${
          process.env.DAUM_GEOCODE
        }&libraries=services`,
        data:{}
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);

 })}
```

Comment: You should **never** try to execute arbitrary JS on your Node server. Remember, *"eval is evil"*

Comment: you can use axios, https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Seblor Could you give me more information about arbitrary JS? it's bcz I don't understand well even though i searched it.

Comment: GeekSambhu How can I put function or method in axios?

Comment: What I mean by "arbitrary JS" is (in your case) JavaScript code that is fetched from a website you have no control over. Even if you have control over it, some people could add malicious code that may destroy your app / server, and is overall a huge security flaw.

Comment: Oh really thank you so much. I didn't figure out that problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)! fro api calling...

```
const axios = require('axios')   

 axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/user/12345',
      data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
      }
    });

axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you but, how can I use 'geocoder.addressSearch(this.addressState.departure.road' this in axios to get the result?

Comment: What is geocoder.addressSearch it looks like some method calling

Comment: Yes, that is a method calling. But when I use axios , i guess I can't use method calling on it. Am I correct?

Comment: axios only send request to the server with some data which you have to provide first execute you method and send the result according to the api